# Cron job to identify multiple visits in the same url?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

using a PHP cron job, how can I output the users who visited the same page over 2 times ?

Here is the mySQL table

```
id  - user - page - timestamp
340 - 1 - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:11:11
339 - 1 - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:10:01
337 - 1 - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:06:00
336 - 2 - page3 - 2009-05-18 22:00:00
335 - 2 - page3 - 2009-05-18 21:56:00
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be done easily with `group by` and `count`

```
select
user,page, count(*) as total
from table_name
group by user,page
having total > 2
```

**UPDATE**

> how can i update another table with these results? user - page - times

This could be done using `insert into select from` in addition using `on duplicate key update`

Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from pages ;
+------+------+
| user | page |
+------+------+
|    1 | p1   |
|    1 | p1   |
|    1 | p1   |
|    2 | p1   |
|    2 | p1   |
|    2 | p2   |
|    3 | p2   |
|    3 | p2   |
|    3 | p2   |
+------+------+



create table page_view_log 
   (
       user int,
       page varchar(100),
       times int,
       primary key(user,page)
    );

select * from page_view_log ;
```

Note that here the log table has composite key  `(user,page)`

Now the following query will do the job

```
insert into page_view_log(user,page,times)
select
user,page,total from (
 select user,page, count(*) as total
 from pages
 group by user,page
 having total > 2
)x
on duplicate key update times = total


mysql> select * from page_view_log ;
+------+------+-------+
| user | page | times |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 | p1   |     3 |
|    3 | p2   |     3 |
+------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now lets add more page in the first table for `user-1`

```
insert into pages values (1,'p1'),(2,'p2'),(2,'p2');
```

Now if we run the above query again it will update the total for existing data and insert new values, the duplicate is considered using the composite key `(user,page)`

```
mysql>  select * from page_view_log ;
+------+------+-------+
| user | page | times |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 | p1   |     4 |
|    2 | p2   |     3 |
|    3 | p2   |     3 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: thank you. so now we found the users with page visiting more than two times. how can i update another table with these results? user - page - times

Comment: Update or insert ? Does the 2nd table will already have the `user` and `page` so that it will only update ?

Comment: The second table will have the columns `user - page - times`. It will be like "insert if not exist otherwise update".

Comment: Really thank you! so the juice is in this block `insert into page_view_log(user,page,times)....`  right?

Comment: Yes.. here I am doing `insert into select from`  and using a composite key checking if its duplicated or not if yes then just update else a new entry.